# Difference between two dates with '%m/%d/%Y' format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one date formatted as '%m/%d/%Y'. I'd like to get the difference in days between my date and today. (mysql)

I have tried all the below without success:

```
timediff(date_format(now(), '%m/%d/%Y'), my_date)
timestampdiff(date_format(now(), '%m/%d/%Y'), my_date)
datediff(date_format(now(), '%m/%d/%Y'), my_date)
```

ps: my_date is already formatted as '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: Please describe "without success" in more detail.  Off the cuff, MM/DD/YYYY is not the internal format that MySQL uses; perhaps that is your issue.

Comment: If your column is of type date then you don't need a date_format. That is just for customizing the output

Comment: Is the data type of `my_date` a varchar? The first args to those 3 functions where you compare to `now()` should not be formatted - MySQL expects them to be actual datetimes rather than formatted strings. If it is varchar, it is `my_date` which you must convert from formatted string to proper datetime type.

Comment: @Michael you are right. Gordon's answer below helped out. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_to_date()`, such as:

```
datediff(curdate(), str_to_date(my_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I simulate mydate as 11/12/2015 (yesterday = nov 12th 2015)

```
SELECT datediff(date(now()), STR_TO_DATE('11/12/2015','%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: Gordons curdate() is a litte bit smarter than date(now())